# Handdrawn like pencil sketch with inkscape

Tags: inkscape, drawing, sketching

I have made this sketch with MS Visio which looks like it is handdrawn with a pencil:
[image]

How can I achieve this with inkscape?

Comment: Do you mind telling us what you have tried?

Comment: Curious, how was this done in Visio?

Answer (score 25):

Inkscape comes with a variety of effect filters we can apply to our drawings. Amongst the many there are some effects to simulate hand-drawings.

We can apply these filter with the menu *Filters > Textures > Name of effect* to all selected objects.

Below are some example effects:

[image]

Comment: Another way is apply `Sketch` effect to the path.

Answer (score 15):

In the context of wireframing, I don't know that there's a simple way to do this in Inkscape, as Inkscape doesn't have the concept of 'brushes' that something like Adobe Illustrator has (making this rather easy to do).

What I have done, however, is made my own 'sketchy' objects just for wireframing. The process was essentially drawing a few UI Primitives (boxes, buttons, etc.) then converting the outlines to shapes, adding extra nodes along each path, then tweaking the position and angle of the nodes to create the 'wiggles'.

Once created, I can then cut-and-paste and stretch and flip things pretty quickly to lay out things.

It ends up looking like this:

[image]

Another option, which is a bit more automated, would be to try and use some of the extensions. The image below was created (from top to bottom) as such:

- Top image:

  - draw object (in this case a rounded box)
- Middle image:

  - go to *Path > Stroke to Path* to turn the path into an object
  - go to *Extensions > Modify Path > Add Nodes*
- bottom image:

  - go to *Extensions > Modify Path > Jitter Nodes*

Play with the settings of the Extensions to tweak the 'scribble-ness' of the images to your liking.

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity: have you noticed any CPU limitations on complexity using so many nodes per object? (i.e. will redraw slow to a crawl or cause export/reuse problems)

Comment: In the former example, no, as I am actually using very few nodes on those (for example, for a box, I'll just add one extra node per side). In the latter example, quite possibly. For that, I'd suggest doing that as an 'end of day' task before final printing rather than keeping your editable file with that many nodes.

Comment: This is a great technique which doesn't rely on raster filters. Changing the parameters on the Jitter gives you a wide range of attractive outputs. Also, performing a Path->Simplify afterwards reduced the nodes to a workable level for me.