# How to create doodles/sketches similar to those on Dropbox home page?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, drawing, sketching

I am new in design, and recently I have been given a task where I have to create images like the ones present on dropbox.com home page.

[image]

I am not sure what is the correct way of creating those images.I suppose they are called doodles.

Can they be created using Photoshop/Illustrator or will I have to use the method where I sketch the image on paper, scan it and then edit in Photoshop?
If there is a way of creating the images other than that, then please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Whatever works for you. There's really no wrong way to create sketch images. I'd guess that the specific device images on dropbox's home page were actually draw in some software though.

Comment: I'd recommend hand drawing the images first and scanning them in. This will give you greater control over your designs and then you can work them up in either Photoshop or Illustrator.

Comment: If you have the patience to get to grips with Inkscape these answers could be of interest. The jitter option is pretty good. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27379/handdrawn-like-pencil-sketch-with-inkscape

Answer (score 1):

I draw  the sketches that i’d like to convert into digital vector art.

I like to use Pigma Micron pens because they come in various thicknesses, are a rich black colour and they write beautifully but use whatever you prefer.

I also like to use tracing paper to sketch on – it’s cheap and there’s a smooth quality to the paper that’s really nice.

Scan my sketches with a flatbed scanner.

Scan at a high resolution of at least 400 dpi while using the greyscale setting.
Open your scanned sketch into Photoshop to convert to digital

**Another Method I Prefer**

There's  better way to draw, paint, or simply doodle than with the use of a Wacom pen tablet. And Bamboo makes it easy, using your favorite software applications and Just pick up the pen and start drawing or painting. Adjust line weight and opacity naturally through the pen's pressure sensitivity.

Answer (score -2):

Use a pen tablet,that might help.

Comment: Hi aniruh, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. Could you please be a bit more specific as to how this is going to help the asker's question? If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!