# How to draw art like Dropbox?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, drawing

[image]

I know some methods.

`1st:` I can draw it on a paper and then trace it in Illustrator. 
`2nd:` I can draw it with pen tablet.

Maybe anyone knows other methods?

Comment: Hi Sam_sky, could you be more specific? _What_ do you want to draw exactly? The logo? Some piece of art from their website? Something else? If you could add an example to your question, that'd be great (you can [edit] you own question to do this). Bear in mind that copying someone else's art is copyright infringement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create doodles/sketches similar to those on Dropbox home page?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30946/how-to-create-doodles-sketches-similar-to-those-on-dropbox-home-page)

Comment: Hi @PieBie. I'm just want to copy their art style.

Comment: Whats wrong with drawing with line tool and mouse?

Comment: @joojaa Lines are too straight when I draw with line tool and mouse.

Comment: @SamSky thats why you have brushes, they will make straight lines crooked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of `Pen Tool`, `Stroke Path...` (Brush) and the `Filter > Distort > Ripple...` (Photoshop CC 2015) filter.

- To create `Pen Tool` outlines you could use photos to get the
  proportions right.
- Make sure to use low saturated colors to make it look more paperlike.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you go into a program like Inkscape or Illustrator and "draw" the image with curves. Then, once you're done with the lines, ever so slightly manipulate the lines so it has all of those little perfect imperfections. This is what I got after about 5 minutes:

[image: Dropbox style image]

I only got to the outer edge of the screen, but hey. Its 5 minutes.