# It is possible to convert a regular shape to a hand-written shape using illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, inkscape, shapes

I want to convert regular forms let's say for example a rectangle and circle to a hand-written looking forms using Illustrator or Inkscape(best scenario).
I don't want to use the pencil to draw the shape using the mouse.

Here is a an image that illustrate better the desired result:

[image]

Comment: For Inkscape: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27379/handdrawn-like-pencil-sketch-with-inkscape

Comment: You can easily do this with brushes. Illustrator comes with some hand-drawn type brushes ready loaded, but there are plenty you can download if they don't suit your needs. Or you can quite easily make your own.

Comment: I get that you don't want to draw the circle, but what about the arrow? If we forget about the style of that arrow for a second... Wouldn't it be the easier for you to draw the arrow to point what ever you want, rather than draw a straight arrow and apply an effect on it that makes it always curve down to the right? [To further illustrate my point, here's a crude example of arrows drawn in Illustrator with a mouse](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eQEZR.gif) ( The arrow head doesn't fit the style of the line, but it can also be changed )

Answer (score 1):

As CAI said you can use different brushes for the line style to give a more hand-drawn effect which works well but that is only half the solution.

To fully complete the look use the warp tool (shift+R) or one of the warp or distort effects or possibly a combination of the above. This will give the imperfects needed for a more authentic hand-drawn look.

Answer (score 1):

In Inkscape you can do this with path effects, simply use the [circle tool](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Shapes-Arcs.html) to create your circle, convert [the object to a path](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Creating.html#Paths-From-Objects) and then use the [path effect editor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pi7Y7xc9qxc) to create your effect.